# Excel If and else statement

Tags: excel, if-statement

[image]

Hi All,

Can somebody please help me with if and else in excel.

My codes seems correct when doing it separately, but when combining them - it does not work.

Codes are as follow:

```
=IFS(E7=Sheet2!$B$4,Sheet2!$C$4,IF(E7=Sheet2!B5,Sheet2!$C$5,"10"),IF(E7=Sheet2!$B$11,Sheet2!$C$11,IF(E7=Sheet2!B12,Sheet2!C12,Sheet2!C13)))
```

the last option still give me #value error.

have the sheet 2 that includes:

```
Merit Score
Low    2
Medium 5  
High  10   

Error   Score
Low   -2 
Medium -4
High -10
```

[image]

Comment: Why not try evaluating your formula?

Comment: I am trying.. Still no for me :(

Comment: What do you mean "no"? https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7

Comment: Without going through your formula in-depth, you have a missing opening paranthesis as per your screenshot....at the start `IFE7....` > `IF(E7....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula seems not to take the value of D7 into consideration. Therefore I wonder whether it should. My formula below takes a different approach. I think it's easier to manage than IFS. Please try it.

```
=INDEX(IF($D$7="Merit",{2,5,10},{-2,-4,-10}),MATCH($E$7,{"Low","Medium","High"},0))
```

Comment: It worked for me! I thank you so much. I tried creating a formula with the value for D7 however, I can't do it. But yours is amazing! Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Note that the expressions in curly braces are, in fact, arrays which can be replaced with references to ranges. Therefore `{"Low","Medium","High"}` could be replaced with $A$2:$A$4 (no curly braces, then), or even a range name, and that same reference could then be used to feed a validation drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

The begining of the code is wrong. See if this works.

**Wrong**

```
=IFS(IFE7=Sheet2!$
```

**Right**

```
=IFS(E7=Sheet2!$
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks for noticing, but the last part still give me #value error.

Comment: =IFS(E7=Sheet2!$B$4,Sheet2!$C$4,IF(E7=Sheet2!B5,Sheet2!$C$5,"10"),IF(E7=Sheet2!$B$11,Sheet2!$C$11,IF(E7=Sheet2!B12,Sheet2!C12,Sheet2!C13)))